# Laptop shuts down because of heat though new fan, 50°C and not in Linux

Tags: laptop, bios, fan, temperature

I have a Dell Studio 1558 notebook that has worked for years. I have cleaned it up once or twice a year (you have to remove the motherboard to access the fan and remove the dust between the fan and the cooler) for about 4 years now.

I didn't use it for a few months and started to try to use it again but it shuts down after a few seconds.

I wanted to clean it but it was already. I guessed the fan was spinning too slowly so I ordered a brand new one. Mounted it, same result.

But I have found out that if I place a big fan under the computer and boot Linux (Kubuntu 14.10) it runs for hours. It can run idle without the external fan but will shutdown quickly if I run glxgears (with reasonnable temperatures -cores and videocard-, way below 60°C).

In linux, I monitor the temp with lm-sensors and when temp raises the fan starts spinning and stops when below 50°C.

It shutsdown inside the BIOS. Since it's not the latest BIOS' version I wanted to install a Windows in order to install the latest BIOS version but it won't let me (shutdown before reaching the "choose the disk").

I also tried running MemTest but it will shutdown after 2mn

So I suspect the problem has to do with temperature.

- It doesn't seem related to the fan (it is new and seems efficient
  enough to lower the temp and stop, waiting for the next temp rise).
- It doesn't seem related to the temp probe (what lm-sensors show seems
  legit with what I feel with my finger on the cooler)

In fact I am quite convinced it is a software/BIOS problem. Since I don't see a way to upgrade the BIOS I'm stuck with this A08 version (latest is A12 but I don't know if they fixed such issues in-between)

I would like to disable this autoshutdown feature : I know this can damage the computer but the other "solution" is to put a nice Core I7 to the garbage.

If I see no other solution I am considering disconnecting the temp sensor and force the fan to be always on (two things I don't know how to do but should be quite simple).

Clues, ideas, questions are welcome.

Edit: the more I think of it, the more I wonder how this machine could stand 85°C in the past and is now limited to ~ 50°C, that can't be only software, something must be broken. I'm thinking of a temp probe. The temperatures I see in Linux are internal probes of the processor/video chipset while I guess the motherboard is powering off based on other probes. I will try to see what they look like. Maybe I have removed some insulator in all these disassemblies/reassemblies.

Comment: When you replaced the fan did you apply new thermal paste?  If you did then you have changed the thermal design of your laptop.  You should be able to create a bootable disk that works outside of Windows to apply the firmware update have you tried that yett?

Comment: I first tried without thermalpaste (there's some kind of silicon-like solid thermal paste on the copper parts provided with the fan+cooler). Since it didn't work, I tried adding real thermalpaste.
I will try the [FreeDOS prebuilt bootable USB flash drive image](http://chtaube.eu/computers/freedos/bootable-usb/) and see if it can run long enough. I know this is highly dangerous but thanks for the idea.

Comment: FreeDos doing nothing on the `c:\\` prompt : shutdown in less than one minute (computer was powered off and externally cooled for 10 minutes before this try).

Comment: Looking through the fixed issues for all bios versions from A08 to A12 on the Dell website, the only fix listed that I think could possibly relate to your issue is the one for version A11, which says 
`Fix "After flash BIOS, system will auto shutdown in Clarksfield CPU + above 4GB RAM" issue`  - maybe try removing some RAM? Source: http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=CN9X6

Comment: Thx @user54791 already tried both RAM modules on their own with no change.